# Postfix and dovecot can not receive mail

Tags: centos, postfix, dovecot

I setup a mail server (with multiple virtual hosts) on a VPS. I used postfix, dovecot, postfixadmin, squirrel and mysql. I can send mail by squirrel, but can not receive any mail. This is my /var/log/maillog

```
Apr 21 16:52:49 vultr postfix/qmgr[8072]: 90BB738C61: from=<mymail@gmail.com>, size=19715, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 21 16:52:49 vultr postfix/qmgr[8072]: warning: connect to transport private/dovecot: Connection refused
Apr 21 16:52:49 vultr postfix/error[8213]: 90BB738C61: to=<info@mysite.ca>, relay=none, delay=0.13, delays=0.13/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

This is the `postconf -n` output:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_command = /usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = mail.onlineprintshop.ca
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
myorigin = onlineprintshop.ca
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_tls_all_clientcerts,reject_unauth_destination,permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = $mynetworks
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/keys/pub.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/keys/prv.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = no
smtpd_tls_req_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = none
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/spool/postfix/smtpd_tls_session_cache
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:8
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 150
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:150
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: dovecot_destination_recipient_limit=1
```

This is the `dovecot -n` output:

```
(Core)  ext3
first_valid_uid = 150
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/%d/%n
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap pop3
ssl = required
ssl_cert = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
```

This is `postconf -M` output:

```
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
smtps      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o 
syslog_name=postfix/smtps -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
pickup     unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

Any idea?

Comment: What's the output of `postconf -M`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
Apr 21 16:52:49 vultr postfix/qmgr[8072]: warning: connect to transport private/dovecot: Connection refused
```

"Connection refused" indicates that there is no process listening to that socket, which is probably /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot . As your `postconf -M` output doesn't list anything about `dovecot` you're missing a line in master.cf, something like:

```
dovecot unix - n n - - pipe
  flags=DRhu argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, after adding  "dovecot unix - n n - - pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}" I encounter this error 
 "pipe: fatal: pipe_command: execvp /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver: No such file or directory"

Comment: Try to search on your filesystem where deliver resides, as it could vary from one distribution to other

Comment: Thanks alphamikevictor , I've done what you told me, and I encounter new error ' dovecot: lda(info@mysite.ca): Fatal: setgid(150 from userdb lookup) failed with euid=5000(vmail), gid=5000(vmail), egid=5000(vmail): Operation not permitted (This binary should probably be called with process group set to 150 instead of 5000(vmail))
' any idea

Comment: So what's the username belonging to uid 150? Use that for the user= parameter

Comment: After some tweaks! i got this error ! (sorry for this long thread) I used mysql and postfixadmin -Apr 24 08:45:15 vultr dovecot: lda: Error: user info@mymail.ca: Mail access for users with UID 150 not permitted (see first_valid_uid in config file, uid from userdb lookup).

Comment: @user1495900 Please update your question with all the changes. It's hard to reconstruct your changes form the comments and read the (log and config) pastes from comments.